# Spring return null when transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions

can you tell me how can I run transaction only for some block of code? I have service functions with @Transactional, and from them I call repository functions where I execute queries. But when query failed, it also failed service function because transaction must be ended. So how could I return null value when repository function failed? I need catch null value when failed, and continue some logic. My Code:

```
public class SomeService{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    public int getSomeValue(){

        MyObj obj = repo.getLastItem(); // this failed because not items in table, so I need here null
        if (obj != null) {
            //some calculations
            return [calculatedValue]
        } else {
            return 1
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I'll tried @davidxxx 's answer and I got this error :

> Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include the code that may throw the exception in a `try/catch` statement and specify that you don't want rollback for this specific exception:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_GET_LAST_ITEM_FAILED = 1;
...
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ExpectedException.class)
public int getSomeValue(){

    try {
      MyObj obj = repo.getLastItem(); // this failed because not items in table, so I need here null   
      if (obj != null) {          
          return calculatedValue();
        }                     
    }
    catch(ExpectedException e){  
       //TODO exception logging
    }

    return DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_LAST_ITEM_FAILED;

}
```

Comment: But when I catch that transaction, transaction didn't end, or will ?

Comment: I found longer error message in stack trace if it could help. Problem is with nested exception, because I call transaction in transaction, but nested transaction is roll-backed. I'm going to try your updated answer

Comment: You probably don't use the Spring API : `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` but the `javax.transaction.Transactional`. Why not use Spring API as you use Spring ?

Comment: fixed with spring's transactions

Comment: Great. And question : if  you use the `@Transactional` from Spring and you remove `rollbackFor` attribute, is it still working ?